# PHP - reset autoload and declared classes

Tags: php, namespaces, reset, classname, autoloader

In PHP I have a function that sets auto-loaders based on which child-site is selected within the parent-site.

The resetting of the auto-loaders goes excellent with the `spl_autoload_unregister` function.

However, what I notice is that when I load a class-file that was already initiated before the child-site, that this 'old' class-file is still used after resetting the auto-loaders.

**Example:**

Parent-site loads `example\namespace\RouterClass` from `c:\parent\site\RouterClass`

Then I reset all auto-loaders and initiate the child-site and set the correct auto-loaders for the child-site.

Then the child-site loads `example\namespace\RouterClass` but instead of getting this file via the new auto-loader from `c:\child\site\RouterClass` it gets the class from the old file as defined by the parent-site.

I see the class registered via the function:

```
get_declared_classes()
```

But I'm not able to reset this variable list. If a reset of this class-cache is possible then PHP has to start a new search for this `RouterClass` and will check the child-site auto-loader to find it.

Second option I checked was `runkit_method_redefine`, but there is no similar function for classes like `runkit_class_redefine`.

Does anyone have an idea of how to reset the declared class list? Or how to achieve the above without renaming all namespaces of the child-site.

Comment: one you include a file, that file is included (duh). what you need to do and why?

Comment: Because then you can change from context within your code and work with one context in framework v1 and with other context in framework v2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. Once a class is declared, it's there for good.

If you need to define autoloaders dynamically, you need to do so before any of the affected classes are loaded.